# How to select random row from table with non-uniform distribution, in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, distribution

This is how I would select a random row from a table with uniform distribution.

```
SELECT * FROM foo OFFSET floor( random() * ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo ) ) ORDER BY bar LIMIT 1;
```

Let's say I would like to select a random row with a non-uniform distribution, say a normal distribution.

Currently, the way I am doing it is:

```
SELECT * FROM foo OFFSET floor( $1 * ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo ) ) ORDER BY bar LIMIT 1;
```

... and work out the value for `$1` prior to executing it.

- Is there a better way to do this?
- Perhaps using built in postgres functions?
- Perhaps without the need for an inner `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Non-linear distribution (like normal) has some elements with P higher than other. How do you decide, what elements have what P?

Comment: Linear distribution of what?  Can you give an example of what you mean by "select a random row with a non-linear distribution"?

Comment: There's no `ORDER BY` here. So ... distributed along what axis? (In general, relational databases suck at picking random rows, or at least PostgreSQL does).

Comment: Igor, Gordon & Graig - I have left out the `ORDER by` clause as it is not relevant to the question. Of course in my actual application I am ordering the query. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: ... that being said, I am also not perfectly sure that ordering by any particular element and then selecting a row at a random index (where the index has a normal distribution) is sufficient to select a random row distributed normally over the ordered attribute. If so, please answer with what the correct approach should be.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this [entry from google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=gjyd3IOrwz4C&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=sql%20non-uniform%20random&source=bl&ots=-vjcg765u2&sig=wQPg-CGf6Ik9a1uzBJvwDj26FBg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RUggVNKTD-H6igK_o4DQAw&ved=0CG0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=sql%20non-uniform%20random&f=false) will be of help.

I believe you're looking for uniform/non-uniform as opposed to linear/non-linear, which probably hindered your search.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the distinction between linear and uniform distributions, you are right, I have indeed mixed up the terms.